# "Been to" vs. "been in"

Tags: prepositions, difference

I would like to know the difference between the sentences as follow:

> I have been to Germany twice.
>
> I have been in Germany twice.

Comment: I have edited to remove the second question. You can ask the second question in a new post.  You have to show how you have tried to answer the question already. Don't post a question without doing any work to answer it yourself. Tell us what work you did to answer the question.

Comment: @James, I am not sure it is that easy to answer. I tried looking up "in"/"to" in some online dictionaries and could not find a specific reference to "country". Do you have a link for the OP?

Comment: This exact question had been asked in [elu.se]: [Difference between "been to" and "been in"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/77603/164776) and has several good answers.

Comment: Also on EL&U [Why do we say “been to” instead of “been in”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424145/why-do-we-say-been-to-instead-of-been-in?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: to go to a place, to be in a place. Come on. I go to work every day. I am in the city,now.

Answer (score 1):

"Been" is sometimes used synonymously with "gone". The second sentence suggests this meaning. The second sentence means "...gone to Germany..."

The first is more awkward, it would perhaps indicate being in Germany but not going there. For example if you stop in Germany in transit.  In most cases you should say "been to Germany" or "gone to Germany".

Comment: "it would perhaps indicate being in Germany but not going there." A better example would be someone who was born in Germany, moved to another country as an infant or young child, and then returned as a foreign exchange student from their new country of residence for a while. They have "been in" Germany twice, but only "been to" Germany once.